# Unable to remove the start menu and desktop shortcuts in NSIS uninstaller

Tags: nsis

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" _?=$INSTDIR'
```

I am using this code to invoke the uninstaller but it could not remove start menu item and desktop link while a normal uninstallation by double clicking is able to remove all these things.

Comment: Maybe you could give us some more sample code and tell us why you are invoking the uninstaller this way? Does it fail on all versions of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [RequestExecutionLevel](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#requestexecutionlevel) in your script? Without it Windows might do some [compatibility hacks](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista) with your shortcuts.

Code like `Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\myapp\myapp.lnk"` should not change behavior just because you launched with `_?=`, is there something special about the shortcuts paths or the way you delete them?

You should try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), it might be able to shed some light on the issue...